# Refreshing listbox binding in a XAML/UI via seperate Thread using CollectionEvent and NotifyPropertyChange

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I wrote a program in C# .NET 4.x that launches a UI, within the UI there is a ListBox, program should refresh the built ListBox at every x amount of time (this part is yet to be built), see XAML below:

```
<Grid.Resources>
      <src:PresortersInfos x:Key="presortersInfos"/>
</Grid.Resources>

<ListBox Name="lblNow" ItemsSource="{StaticResource presortersInfos}" Width="118" Margin="61,257,0,65" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="8">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" TargetUpdated="OnTargetUpdated"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumofItemsPresent, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" TargetUpdated="OnTargetUpdated"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And here is the code that updates the listbox above but only at launching (initial start of the application):

```
public class PresortersInfo
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String NumofItemsPresent { get; set; }

    public PresortersInfo(String name, String numofItemsPresent)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.NumofItemsPresent = numofItemsPresent;
    }
}

public class PresortersInfos : ObservableCollection<PresortersInfo>
{
    List<TrackingType> DataList = new List<TrackingType>();

    SharedMemoryFile memoryfile = new SharedMemoryFile(@"\\serveName\c$\data\files\fileName.dat");
    string errorString = null;

    public PresortersInfos()
    {
        int numofLoops = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["numberofSystems"]);
        string[] system_names = new string[numofLoops];
        system_names = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["arrayVar"].Split(',');

        memoryfile.ReadAllitems(out DataList, out errorString);
        int counterofitemsinSystem= 0;
        int i = 0;

        while (i < numofLoops)
        {
            counterofitemsinSystem= DataList.Where(f => f.LastRID.ToString().Contains(system_names[i]) & f.Flag == true).Count();
            Add(new PresortersInfo("SystemName" + system_names[i], counterofitemsinSystem.ToString()));
            i++;
        }  
    }
}
```

Need to be able to refresh the ListBox (more specifically "Name" and "NumofItemsPresent") after initially adding the information to it when application first initialized. And this task should be done on a separate thread from the rest of the program, such thread should run at x amount of time. I would be very thankful if you can provide me with the rest of the code to carry our such task.